# Vetor em OpenGL

Tags: c, array, for, opengl

OLá, estou me aventurando em OpenGL e até agora sei o básico de criar figuras. Eu preciso criar um número de barras que vai de 1 até 64, o problema é que preciso fazer isso com um FOR. Quando o primeiro contador do for começa, ele cria a primeira barra e ao mudar o contador ele cria outra barra e a primeira some. Pelo que entendi até agora, não é como se ele criasse outra barra, e sim mudasse a posição da primeira.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algum tipo de fazer isso como se fosse um vetor, tipo glBegin[jk] para que eu possa criar um numero definido de barras?

Comment: Então amigo, é que a palavra "indefinido" não entra no dicionário de vetores haha você sempre tem que definir um tamanho pro vetor, não importa se for dinamicamente ou estaticamente.

Comment: Digamos que meu vetor seja de 64 elementos, como faço pra gerar essas 64 barras?

Comment: Exatamente, você entendeu de uma forma correta, ele não está criando e sim apenas mudando a posição da mesma

Comment: Isso, mas pra criar as outras 63 eu teria que repetir o codigo? Nao tem como fazer num loop?

Comment: Cria um método, onde você vai passar a posição pra desenhar, tipo

gl,DrawSquare(posição,...) ai cada vez você vai chamando este método dentro do seu for, para ser mais preciso, tira do glBegin ao end, e só não coloca o while e coloca dentro de um método, ai você chama este método dentro desse for e vai alimentando sua função... entende ?

Comment: Ou então, você cria uma classe com um construtor que são os parametros de posições que será passado para os quadrados, depois voce cria um método que vai alimentar através desses parametros, criando a classe, você consegue criar um Vetor dessa classe, daí é só ir instanciando ela e alimentando com valores diferentes.

Comment: na verdade não, eu só aprendi usando o glvertex2f

Comment: Você aidna continuará usando o glvertex2f

Comment: Quando voce fala em metodo, fala em função?

Comment: consegui adaptando alguns parametros

Comment: Boa cara, agora manda haver no seu código haha